# Как проверить объекты в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Начал изучать массивы и объекты (не очень хорошо усваивается)
задали ДЗ :

> Написать простую программу авторизации. Создать массив `users`, в
>   котором каждый элемент – это объект типа “пользователь” со свойствами
>   “имя”, “логин” и “пароль”. Программа должна запрашивать у пользователя
>   логин и пароль при помощи `prompt()`, после чего проходить по массиву
>   `users` и искать в нем объект с такими же значениями. Если пользователь
>   найден в массиве `users`, то программа должна поздороваться с ним по
>   имени. В противном случае должна появиться ошибка авторизации.

Вопрос, как правильно сделать проверку *name*, *login*, *password* для каждого объекта

```
var users = [];

users[0] = {
  name:"nikita",
  login:"nikita@",
  password:"iii",
};  

users[1] = { 
  name:"alex",
  login:"alex@",
  password:"lll"
};


var name = prompt('Введите свое имя');
var login = prompt('Введите свой логин');
var password = prompt('Введите пароль ');

if (name == users[0] && login == users[0] && password == users[0]) {
  alert('здравствуй'+' '+name+' добро пожаловать в личный кабинет');
} else if (name == '' || login == '' || password == '') {
  alert('Вы ввели не все данные');
} else if (name == users[1] && login == users[1] && password == user[1]) {
  alert('Здравствуй'+ ' ' +name+' добро пожаловать в личный кабинет');
} else alert ('проверьте правильность ввода данных');
```

Comment: до объектов  у вас не было главы про циклы? и вводить/проеврять надо только логин/пароль. имя трогать не надо.

Comment: глава про циклы была

Comment: Вопрос, "как правильно сделать проверку name,login,password для каждого объекта"

Comment: "_Программа должна запрашивать у пользователя **логин и пароль**_"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам нужно проверить массив, то делать это надо в цикле. Проходите по массиву, сравниваете значения. Если нашли, то выходите из цикла. Что-то вроде

```
let user = null;
for(let i = 0; i< users.length; i++){
   if(users[i].login == login && users[i].password == pwd){
       user = users[i];
       break;
   } 
}
```

и далее проверяете, что получилось

```
if(user) ...
else ...
```

либо с помощью встроенных функций массивов

```js
const users = [
  {name: 'Вася', password: 'Vasya123', login: 'Vasya'},
  {name: 'Петя', password: 'Petya123', login: 'Petya'},
  {name: 'Дима', password: 'Dima123', login: 'Dima'}
];

let login = prompt('логин');
let pwd   = prompt('пароль');

let user = users.find(u => (u.login == login && u.password == pwd));

if(user){
  console.log('hey ' + user.name);
}
else console.log(':(')
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ 

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего проходить массив в цикле

```js
const users_account= [
      {name: 'Вася', login: 'Vasya123', password: 'Vasya'},
      {name: 'Петя', login: 'Petya123', password: 'Petya'},
      {name: 'Дима', login: 'Dima123', password: 'Dima'}
    ]
    // const и let можно заменить на var если вы этого не проходили ещё
    let user_asw = {
      login: prompt('login'),
      password: prompt('password') 
    }
    
    for (let i = 0; i < users_account.length; i++) {
      if (user_asw.login === users_account[i].login && user_asw.password === users_account[i].password) {
        alert('Привет, ' + users_account[i].name);
        break;
      } else if (i === users_account.length - 1) {
        alert('Такого пользователя нету :( ');
      }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь 